# OpenCV GpuMat dot product

Tags: c++, opencv, cublas

I'm currently developing on an Nvidia Jetson TX1/2.

The slowest part of my code is (variable name changed for readability):

```
....
cv::Mat A, B;
GpuMat_A.download(A, Cuda_stream);
GpuMat_B.download(B, Cuda_stream);
double C = A.dot(B);

B = B.inv() * C;
GpuMat_B.upload(B, Cuda_stream);
....
```

I never used GpuMat before, and it seems that the dot product & the inv() functions don't exist forcing me to download() and upload() from & to Gpu to RAM.

Those downloads & uploads takes 3ms ~ but this is repeated in an iterative loop, then costing me 45ms on a 55ms process.

1) Did I miss those in the doc? (invert & dot are standard operation in computer vision, so I thought that they should exist).

2) If not, what will be the most efficient way (if possible) to do both of those on the Gpu side?

Update: 1) It seems that GpuMat doesn't have a "native" dot product.

So here is what Im trying to do: (for now just get the 1st row of A & first col of B and do the vector Dot product)

```
void GpuMat_Dot(GpuMat& A, GpuMat& B, double& dot)
{
    CV_ASSERT(A.type() == B.type() && A.rows == B.cols && A.cols == B.rows);
    const double* Ptr_first_row = A.ptr(0); //const _Tp GpuMat::Ptr()
    const double* Ptr_first_col = &B.ptr(0)[0]; //I couldn't find a equivalent of Ptr() that return the col address directly also this might be wrong
    dot = cublasDdot((int)A.cols, Ptr_first_row, A.elemsize()/*1 ?*/, Ptr_first_col, B.elemsize()/*1 */);
}
```

it does compile (editing from phone typo might exist), but the result is not what it is supposed to be...

Answer (score 1):

Try matrix inversion through CUBLAS by grabbing the raw pointer inside the GPU mat, same thing with dot product.

Note that inverting a large matrix is far from straight forward, and is typically an iterative process.

A more paradigmatic way to use the GPU is through the "unified" UMat interface.

Comment: Thank for the pretty fast answer. As Im pretty new to that could you give me a dummy example? I guess that setting a mat the mat to cv::UMat B should allow me to do classic gpu operation and call CUBLAS fonctions? as B.whateverThatGpuMatHas() and cublas_dot(B, C) (still checking CUBLAS API)

Answer (score 0):

For the dot product, my recommendation is to use the [NVIDIA Performance Primitives](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html), if all of your images have the same size you can write a version with a precomputed buffer for better performance.

```
double dotGpuMat(cv::cuda::GpuMat m1, cv::cuda::GpuMat m2)
{
    int hpBufferSize;
    Npp8u *pDeviceBuffer;
    NppiSize ns;
    double pDp;
    double *pDp_dev;

    ns.height = m1.rows;
    ns.width = m1.cols;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&pDp_dev, sizeof(double));
    nppiDotProdGetBufferHostSize_32f64f_C1R(ns, &hpBufferSize);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&pDeviceBuffer, sizeof(Npp8u)*hpBufferSize);
    nppiDotProd_32f64f_C1R(m1.ptr<Npp32f>(), static_cast<int>(m1.step), m2.ptr<Npp32f>(), static_cast<int>(m2.step), ns, pDp_dev, pDeviceBuffer);
    cudaMemcpy(&pDp, pDp_dev, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(pDeviceBuffer);
    cudaFree(pDp_dev);
    return pDp;
}
```

The inverse is more complex. First of all, GpuMat is not guaranteed to be continuous. Second, if I understand correctly, Gpumat is stored in a row major order and Cusolver works with column major order. So you need a pair of kernels to copy the GpuMat to a float array and viceversa, and another one to create identity matrices.

```
#define IDX2C(i,j,ld) (((j)*(ld))+(i))
#define _x_ threadIdx.x
#define _y_ blockIdx.x
#define _i_ blockIdx.x
#define _j_ threadIdx.x
#define _ld_ gridDim.x

__global__ void copyDataGpuMat2Array(cv::cuda::PtrStepSzf src, float *dst)
{
    dst[IDX2C(_i_, _j_, _ld_)] = src(_y_, _x_);
}

__global__ void copyDataArray2GpuMat(float *src, cv::cuda::PtrStepSzf dst)
{
    dst(_y_, _x_) = src[IDX2C(_i_, _j_, _ld_)];
}

__global__ void eye(float *srcDst)
{
    if (_i_ == _j_)
        srcDst[IDX2C(_i_, _j_, _ld_)] = 1;
    else
        srcDst[IDX2C(_i_, _j_, _ld_)] = 0;
}

cv::cuda::GpuMat inverse_wr(const cv::cuda::GpuMat &m)
{
    float *d_m, *d_minv;
    cusolverDnHandle_t handle;
    int *d_pivot, *d_info, Lwork;
    float *d_Work;
    cv::cuda::GpuMat minv;

    if (m.rows != m.cols )//m must be square
        return cv::cuda::GpuMat();

    cusolverDnCreate(&handle);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_m   , sizeof(float)*m.rows*m.cols);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_minv, sizeof(float)*m.rows*m.cols);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_pivot, m.rows * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_info, sizeof(int));

    copyDataGpuMat2Array<<<m.rows, m.cols>>>(m, d_m);
    eye<<<m.rows, m.cols>>>(d_minv);

    cusolverDnSgetrf_bufferSize(handle, m.rows, m.rows, d_m, m.rows, &Lwork);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_Work, Lwork * sizeof(float));
    cusolverDnSgetrf(handle, m.rows, m.rows, d_m, m.rows, d_Work, d_pivot, d_info);
    cusolverDnSgetrs(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, m.rows, m.rows, d_m, m.rows, d_pivot, d_minv, m.rows, d_info);

    minv = cv::cuda::GpuMat(m.rows, m.cols, CV_32FC1);
    copyDataArray2GpuMat<<<m.rows, m.cols>>>(d_minv, minv);

    cudaFree(d_Work);
    cudaFree(d_pivot);
    cudaFree(d_info);
    cudaFree(d_m);
    cudaFree(d_minv);

    cusolverDnDestroy(handle);
    return minv;
}
```

PS: For simplicity, I didn't write any kind of safeguard in the code.